# Load an embedded html file into a webrowser control and replace img tags to point to embedded images

Tags: c#, resources, browser

I want to show a html document in a web browser control (WinForms). The html file should contain images, that are embedded resources.

How can I modify the html that is shown in the webbrowser to replace the src attribute of the img tags to somehow show the embedded resource without copying it into the file system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use  `src="data:image/png;base64,....` and replace the `....` with the base64 encoded string.

You'll need to replace the `src="url"` for the img tags in the given HTML, which means you would have to store the HTML somewhere on disk temporarily, so I guess doesn't solve the problem, unless you have access to the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

As you know Data URI's have problem with older browsers (IE < 8)
so :

1. You can [use MHTML manner to save your embedding images](http://www.phpied.com/data-uris-mhtml-ie7-win7-vista-blues/).
2. You can [make Data URI's with this kind of javascript](http://web.archive.org/web/20080702001125/http://ddzoom.net/jsimages/out.htm).